# How to get the current logged User in an ASP.NET Core WebApi Controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

ASP.NET Core 3.1  Web Api
VS 2019

I am testing using postman to call my Web Api and retrieve a token and the use that token to access other actions that require authorization.

I pass in a User/Password (User is in the AspNetUsers table in a DB) and I get a token returned.

I then pass that in the header of all requests:

Authorization bearer token

This works fine.  When I call the following controller action..

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("Whoopee");
}
```

It executes the action, so I must be logged on as there is an [Authorize] attribute..

What I am struggling with is... In the action, how do I get the currently logged on User (i.e. The one who is calling the action)?  The User I retrieved from the database when they authenticated?

Incidentally, if it is relevant, here is my authentication code (_appsettings.Issuer/Audience are just a domain name, TokenLifeTimeInHours is 2):

```
public async Task<string> Authenticate(string userName, string password)
{
    // Check the User exists
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

    if (user != null)
    {
        // Verify the correct password has been supplied
        bool passwordCorrect = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);

        if (passwordCorrect)
            return GenerateToken();
    }

    return null;
}

private string GenerateToken()
{
    // Obtain the "Secret" key
    var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret));

    // Create the token
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _appSettings.Issuer,
        audience: _appSettings.Audience,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(_appSettings.TokenLifeTimeHours),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
        .WriteToken(token);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're using JWT authentications scheme. If that's the case, you should pass the claims when creating the token.

```
private string GenerateToken(List<Claim> userClaims) 
{
    ...
    // Create the token
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _appSettings.Issuer,
        audience: _appSettings.Audience,
        claims: userClaims,             // add this line 
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(_appSettings.TokenLifeTimeHours),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
        .WriteToken(token);
}
```

And invoke this method as below:

```
public async Task<string> Authenticate(string userName, string password)
{
    ...
        if (passwordCorrect){
            var claims = new List<Claim>(){
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,          ...),  // add the name claim
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,         ...),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,          ...),
                ...                                        // add other claim if you like
            };
            return GenerateToken();
            return GenerateToken(claims);
        }
    ...
}
```

---

Finally, you can get the user principal with the builtin `User` property in Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // now you get the User property
    return Ok("Whoopee");
}
```

You can also get the current user by `HttpContext.User` if you want to use it in Filter/Middleware/Services

Comment: Thanks, this has put be on the right track.  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName) then allowed me to use User.Identity.Name to get the UserName in my controller action.  This answers my question. And for Roles (for the time being)  when adding the claims I just loop through the user's roles and add them as claims and my current role based authorization works too.

Answer (score 1):

The `ClaimsPrincipal` representing the user is on `HttpContext.User`. Inside of a controller, view, etc., you can access it as just `User`. However, this will only contain the claims that were set at authentication; it likely will not be the full user object you persisted to the database. If *that* is what you need, then you can inject `UserManager<TUser>` and then do:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Comment: Chris.  If I use that format in my controller then user is null.  User  (uppercase U) has my claims attached to it.  I am injecting UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager where ApplicationUser derives from IdentityUser.  If I do var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);  Then I get the full user